# GWT FileUpload issue: Content-Type was 'multipart/form-data; Expected 'text/x-gwt-rpc'

Tags: gwt

I have some troubles uploading a file to server. I used this tutorial: http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/GwtUpload_GettingStarted and everything went well, but when I select a file the progress bar doesn't show any progress and in Eclipse I get:

[WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
javax.servlet.ServletException: Content-Type was 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----webkitformboundaryfafzb7tzbpq9rkjl'. Expected 'text/x-gwt-rpc'.
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPCServletUtils.checkContentTypeIgnoreCase(RPCServletUtils.java:476)
....

I started adding the code from tutorial on top of HelloWorld initial project from GWT.

This is my web.xml file

```
<context-param>
    <!-- max size of the upload request -->
    <param-name>maxSize</param-name>
    <param-value>3145728</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <!-- Useful in development mode to slow down the uploads in fast networks. 
        Put the number of milliseconds to sleep in each block received in the server. 
        false or 0, means don't use slow uploads -->
    <param-name>slowUploads</param-name>
    <param-value>200</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Servlets -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>webapp.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>

    <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <!-- This is the default servlet, it puts files in session -->
    <servlet-class>webapp.server.CustomizedUploadServlet</servlet-class>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/singlefileuploadsample/greet</url-pattern>

    <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gupld</url-pattern>

    <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/upload</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Default page to serve -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>SingleFileUploadSample.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

For the servlet, I created a new class and added the code in there.
There is something related to the content type, but I can't figure out how to solve this problem.

UPDATE:

This happens only in Eclipse when I try to deploy the project on Jetty. I works perfectly fine once deployed as war file on Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You cant post a form with files to be uploaded to a RPC service. Your service which extends the RPC servlet cannot receive forms but can only take proper objects.

Answer (score 0):

I use [gwtupload](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/) for my file upload

```java
import gwtupload.server.UploadAction;
import gwtupload.server.exceptions.UploadActionException;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;

public class CWTUploadServlet extends UploadAction {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  Hashtable<String, String> receivedContentTypes = new Hashtable<String, String>();
  /**
   * Maintain a list with received files and their content types. 
   */
  Hashtable<String, File> receivedFiles = new Hashtable<String, File>();

  /**
   * Override executeAction to save the received files in a custom place
   * and delete this items from session.  
   */
  @Override
  public String executeAction(HttpServletRequest request, List<FileItem> sessionFiles) throws UploadActionException {
    String response = "";
    int cont = 0;
    for (FileItem item : sessionFiles) {
      if (false == item.isFormField()) {
        cont++;
        try {

           //Create a new file based on the remote file name in the client
           String saveName = item.getName().replaceAll("[\\\\/><\\|\\s\"'{}()\\[\\]]+", "_");
           System.out.println("Save name : "+saveName);
           File file =new File("/Users/Spirit/hob/" + saveName);

          item.write(file);
          /// Save a list with the received files
          receivedFiles.put(item.getFieldName(), file);
          receivedContentTypes.put(item.getFieldName(), item.getContentType());

          /// Compose a xml message with the full file information
          response += "<file-" + cont + "-field>" + item.getFieldName() + "</file-" + cont + "-field>\n";
          response += "<file-" + cont + "-name>" + item.getName() + "</file-" + cont + "-name>\n";
          response += "<file-" + cont + "-size>" + item.getSize() + "</file-" + cont + "-size>\n";
          response += "<file-" + cont + "-type>" + item.getContentType() + "</file-" + cont + "type>\n";
        } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new UploadActionException(e);
        }
      }
    }

    /// Remove files from session because we have a copy of them
    removeSessionFileItems(request);

    /// Send information of the received files to the client.
    return "<response>\n" + response + "</response>\n";
  }
```

And your web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>CWTMVP</display-name>

    <!-- Default page to serve -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>CWTMVP.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!--
        This Guice listener hijacks all further filters and servlets. Extra
        filters and servlets have to be configured in your
        ServletModule#configureServlets() by calling
        serve(String).with(Class<? extends HttpServlet>) and
        filter(String).through(Class<? extends Filter)
    -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.db.cawt.clientzonedesign.server.guice.GuiceServletConfig</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


      <context-param>
        <param-name>maxSize</param-name>
        <param-value>102400000</param-value>
      </context-param>

      <context-param>
        <param-name>slowUploads</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
      </context-param>

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>xxx.yyy.server.CWTUploadServlet</servlet-class>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.gupld</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but it still doesn't work. The problem is related to the content type. I keep getting this error: Content-Type was 'multipart/form-data; Expected 'text/x-gwt-rpc'.

Answer (score 0):

Your error trace says that the servlet which has received the request you sent is a gwt-rpc servlet.

It seems your web.xml is configured correctly and it is supposed according with that file that your webapp.server.CustomizedUploadServlet handled the request, so the only possible causes of the error I see are:

- your webapp.server.CustomizedUploadServlet is extending RPCServlet instead of UploadAction.
- or your deploy is wrong and your app is not reading the correct web.xml

Comment: My CustomizedUploadServlet is extending UploadAction. Can you be more specific on the second point? what is it that I'm doing wrong or what should I look for? I can post the rest of the code if you believe might give the answer, but as I said in the question I just copy pasted the code from the tutorial in the HelloWorld initial project which Eclipse adds it to a new web application.

Comment: As you know when you deploy an app in dev-mode it copies the web.xml from your source folder to the deploy one, so it is possible that those web.xml are desynchronized.

Comment: You could try to see which url is being used in the gwtupload requests (take a look to firebug net output), them try to request manually that url which your browser, gwtupload servlet should respond with something like listener is null, otherwise a different servlet is answering your request

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Ironically this happens only in Eclipse on Jetty. Once deployed on Tomcat it works as expected. This is quite unusual because most of the people who complained about this problem they were having the opposite problem. Still don't know how to make it work in devmode

Comment: In devmode it should work exactly the same than in production. Have you tried to download the example project from google code and run in your eclipse? it works to me

Answer (score 0):

mP is correct, you can't post a form with files to a RPC servlet. So instead of extending RemoteServiceServlet create a servlet that extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet. 
I just made this change myself (using the code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420851/calling-servlet-on-submiting-formpanel-in-gwt) question) and succeeded uploading a file.